# How to remove .0 from decimal value in FROM OPENJSON( ) WITH in SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, string-parsing, open-json

I want to remove .0 from value of '123.0'.

Actually value of `$.Item2` is '123.0' .I want to convert it to '123' removing .0

I tried as below but didn't worked

```
 SELECT Item1,Item2,Item3
 FROM OPENJSON( @DataTable  )
 WITH (Item1 NVARCHAR(100) '$.Item1'
        , Item2 NVARCHAR(100) LEFT('$.Item2', CHARINDEX('.',  '$.Item2') - 1) 
        , Item3 NVARCHAR(100) '$.Item3'    
        );
```

Kindly suggest.

**Sample Data:**

- Item1: '234-00945'
- Item2: '7512345671195.0'
- Item3: '5027501.0'

Comment: which db you are using ??'

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2017

Comment: Can you please add some more sample data for `Item1,Item2,Item3`

Comment: Added more sample data

Comment: how do you want to convert `234-00945`.

Comment: Actually all three items values are nvarchar(100). Some Items may have values as "7512345671195.0".I want to remove .0 from "7512345671195.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing it from `charindex`, since this value is decimal so directly convert it into `bigint` as of your value.

```
 SELECT Item1,
case when Item2 like '%.0' then 
substring(Item2 , 1 , PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', Item2) - 1) else Item2  end as Item2,
Item3    --- cast over here
 FROM OPENJSON( @DataTable  )
 WITH (Item1 NVARCHAR(100) '$.Item1'
        , Item2 NVARCHAR(100) '$.Item2'
        , Item3 NVARCHAR(100) '$.Item3'    
        );


For example---

Declare @query varchar(max) 

set @query = '7512345671195.00'

select substring(@query, 1 , PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @query)-1)


Result
-------
7512345671195
```

Comment: I'm getting error " The conversion of the nvarchar value '7512345671195.0' overflowed an int column. "

Comment: @chandrasekhar: I've updated my ans use `bigint` instead of `int`.

Comment: Another error "Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint."

Comment: PATINDEX didn't worked.Getting values as only '7' instead of '7512345671195'

Comment: I am not sure how this didn;t work added example in my ans, please check again, might be because previously I writed `item2` in single quote `'`, updated my ans, check again now

Comment: It worked but I have another issue. Item2 may have value as "234-00945" instead of "7512345671195.0" . So my requirement is, if Item2 have any type value either int or  nvarchar , I want to remove .0 from value if it exists.

Comment: PATINDEX returning  "234-00945"  as just "234".It want to have value as "234-00945"

Comment: updated my ans with case, as you needed only if `.0` will come in the last then it will remove '.0' else give exact value.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a cast as INT

```
         SELECT CAST (your_value AS INT)
         ....
```

of if you need  string

```
         SELECT CAST(CAST(your_value AS INT)  AS  NVARCHAR(100))
         ....
```

Comment: I'm getting error as  "The conversion of the nvarchar value '7512345671195.0' overflowed an int column."

Comment: answer  updated .. enlarging the varchar and using nvarchar

Answer (score 1):

As your values are alphanumerical codes, any approach with a cast to a number type will fail.

This is my suggestion:

```
DECLARE @YourJSON NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'{"Item1":"234-00945","Item2":"7512345671195.0","Item3":"5027501.0"}';
```

--We use a `CASE` to test the final 2 characters and cut them away, if needed:

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN RIGHT(Item1,2)='.0' THEN SUBSTRING(Item1,1,LEN(Item1)-2) ELSE Item1 END AS Item1
       ,CASE WHEN RIGHT(Item2,2)='.0' THEN SUBSTRING(Item2,1,LEN(Item2)-2) ELSE Item2 END AS Item2
       ,CASE WHEN RIGHT(Item3,2)='.0' THEN SUBSTRING(Item3,1,LEN(Item3)-2) ELSE Item3 END AS Item3
 FROM OPENJSON( @YourJSON  )
   WITH (Item1 NVARCHAR(100) '$.Item1'
        ,Item2 NVARCHAR(100) '$.Item2'
        ,Item3 NVARCHAR(100) '$.Item3'    
        );
```

Any attempt with `CAST` will lead to errors.
Using `TRY_CAST` would work, but might cut away something like `.123` too.
And something like `123.6` would lead to a *round-up* and come back as `124`.

### Hint

In general it is very important to stick to the right type. Your codes are strings, although some of them look like numbers...

### UDATE: The same but without the repeating CASE expression

You can use the following (or create an UDF):

```
 SELECT p.*
 FROM
 (
 SELECT Cleaned.*
 FROM OPENJSON( @YourJSON  ) TheJsonItems
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT TheJsonItems.[key]
                   ,CASE WHEN RIGHT(TheJsonItems.[value],2)='.0' 
                         THEN SUBSTRING(TheJsonItems.[value],1,LEN(TheJsonItems.[value])-2) 
                         ELSE TheJsonItems.[value] END) Cleaned(ItemName,ItemValue)
 ) t
 PIVOT(MAX(t.ItemValue) FOR t.ItemName IN(Item1,Item2,Item3)) p
```